# "Segemented" foreign keys in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with foreign keys in MySQL or probably I am just thinking in the wrong direction... I have an activity log table where I need to reference key values from currently 2 other tables. So I am using a field that contains that foreign key value along with an indicator stating which table that foreign key value is from.

```
Table activitylog
    ...
    RefID INT NOT NULL,
    RefType INT NOT NUL,
    ...

Table offers
    OfferID INT NOT NULL,
    ...

Table orders
    OrderID INT NOT NULL,
    ...
```

If the user created an offer, the value of OfferID from table Offers would be writtten to RefID of activity log and RefType is set to 1. If it was an order then the value of OrderID goes into RefID and RefType is set to 2.

Of course I could add an additional field, name it OrderID, rename RefID to OfferID and discard RefType and use these fields. But if in future an new entity will be used I would have to add an additional field holding the key values of the new entity instead of just invent RefType 3 and continue having the key values in RefID.

I am now struggling with the definition of the foreing key constraints. The logic would be if RefType = 1 lookup the key in Offers, if RefType = 2 go into Orders.

Does anybody know if there is a way to achieve my current concept or do I have to add additional fields to the activitylog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. MySQL doesn't support enforcement of FOREIGN KEY constraints like you explain, a single column referencing multiple tables.

You could define the constraints with the MyISAM engine, but the FK constraints wouldn't be enforced.

If you define the FK constraints for tables using the InnoDB engine, then ALL of the foreign key constraints would be enforced, no matter what values are stored in other columns.

To have FK constraints on a table to reference two (or more) different, independent parent tables, you'd need two (or more) foreign keys columns, one for each table.

With your table design with InnoDB, you'd have to forgo declarative FOREIGN KEY constraints.

It might be possible for you to roll-your-own constraints by writing some messy triggers; have the trigger throw an exception when one of your constraint rules is violated.

Comment: Thank you very much, Spencer, I already had a suspicion that the idea might have been too sophisticated but it was quite appealing. So I will go with distinct fields for each entity. Thanks!

Comment: The kind of functionality does have some appeal. Unfortunately, it isn't currently supported using declarative constraints.

Comment: The appeal has been from the software maintenance point of view: adding a new entity would mean to introduce an additional RefType and continue to put the reference values into RefID. Without this functionality every new entity means a change in the database structure, i.e. in adding a field to the table.